# How can I reproduce a similar effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

New member and my first question here

I'd like to know how to reproduce this ''fax'' and ''eroded/distressed'' effect on texts and images

[image]
[image]

Comment: Print it in low resolution and scan it in :D

Comment: @BillyKerr so far I tried halftone-ing and b&w gradient maps but it doesn't seem to produce the same effect

Comment: @WELZ I thought about that but I'm trying to keep it in high-resolution since I need to create this effect on a big poster, any other suggestions that might help ? otherwise I'll try what you said

Comment: This effect by nature is a blurry (low resolution) effect

Comment: @WELZ Thank you for the quick answer, I just tried the print and scan in low-res and distorted it a little bit more on PS and worked like a charm

Comment: I'd try: `Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur...` - Just a little bit. You'll want to be able to still read the text and recognize shapes. Then: `Image > Adjustments > Threshold...` - Adjust that to fit the image content. Might want to make multiple copies of the image layer with different blur levels and Threshold levels. Might also be interesting to try to scale or move some of the layer duplicates.

Comment: @Joonas - that should really be an answer. If it was, I'd upvote it.

Comment: @BillyKerr, I guess you're right. I figured there's no reason for me to make a proper answer if the OP already figured out the scanning method... but that's really no reason not to give an alternative...

Answer (score 3):

Although for traditional designing this is a terrible idea... for what you need it's perfect.

Just make the project b&w (if not done yet) then print it out and scan it back in in low resolution (you can even use your phone to do this).

#### Original Image:

[image]

#### Added some noise and made B&W in PS

by using BW filter and [dropping the color values to lowest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l2Rf.png) (to add to it's effect)

[image]

At this point, it pretty much has the effect... but for extra realism, I went ahead and printed it out and rescanned it in low res using a scanner app on my phone.

[image]

And after [playing with the levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4R3H.png) for 15 seconds:

[image]

And the Curves:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An alternative for similar effects would be the [G'MIC Tools](http://gmic.eu/) that come as a plugin for Gimp or as [free online version](https://gmicol.greyc.fr/).

Below I used the the *Black & White > Threshold Etch* Filter with default and rather exaggerated filter settings:

[image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to simulate something along these lines would be to use `Image > Adjustments > Threshold...` or `Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Threshold...`.

Depending on the original image and what you want, this on its own gets you pretty far. You can also add additional filters to go crazy with it.

---

This next part is just to illustrate how you could get different looks by experimenting with different filters and techniques.

I just couldn't bring myself to go super over the top with it in terms of just making the picture indistinguishable from the original, like in your example images. I just really wanted to retain readability...

**This is what I did**:

1. `Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur...`

   - A tiny bit of blur. I find that this gives you some flexibility with the next `Threshold` effect. This allows you to make the result thinner or thicker quite easily.
2. `Filter > Distort > Ripple...`

   - I liked the way just a hint of ripple added a little randomness to it.
   - I also tested out different filters, like Shape blur and Motion blur and others... all of which gave pretty interesting results.
3. `Image > Adjustments > Threshold...`

   - The bigger the value, the thicker the outcome.
4. I also overlayed crumpled paper texture on top of it all using blend mode: Multiply and I adjusted its levels to kind of match the look of the rest of the document. In other words, I made it look *very* blown out
5. I also used that same paper texture as a displacement map: `Filter > Distort > Displace...`

   - This distorts the images to sort of match the crumpled paper texture, which helps sell the paper texture.
   - I mayhaps went a little overboard with this effect... Like who faxes crumpled up documents like these anyways.

You should always look at reference images when doing stuff like this... I didn't, but that's beside the point...

( Click to enlarge )

[image]
[image]

**More things:**

- I put the original layer in a Smart Object and used `Image > Adjustments` and `Filters` so I would retain editability. Because of this, I could basically take document, changed the contents and easily replicate the same effect.
- I had to duplicate and mask out the top part of the document and apply different settings to retain that top text, which otherwise just blended in with the rest of that black box.

[image]